# Save the file as new version using specific name in a new location

Tags: excel, filenames, vba

I have a original excel file, every time I have to save it as a new version in a specific file with a specific name base on the name i key in in cell D7, without overwrite the original file. I try record the macro however fail to make it more dynamic (**name it base on the name i key in cell D7**). Help is appreciated...

```
Sub Macro4()
    Range("D7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "walaoei"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\kutan\Desktop\walaoei.xlsm", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Macro4()
    Range("D7").Value = "walaoei"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\kutan\Desktop\" & _
                          Range("D7").Value & ".xlsm", _
                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
                          CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, if i want the file name to be any name that i key in cell D7 which mean as follow

first step: i open the original file
second step: i key in the name in cell D7
third step: run macro to save as the file base on the name i just key in in cell D7 without overwrite the original file

Comment: anyway to do it please?

Comment: just remove the line `Range("D7").Value = "walaoei"` from the above code and then do what you mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Thanks pro, it works. It is just that easy but took me few hours to think about it, I need more exercise. Sigh....